# Google spreadsheet, sort adds a bunch of rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, sorting

I have a function that sorts a table, unfortunately when I call my function it adds a bunch of empty rows at the bottom that I don't like.

```
var kotlijst = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  .getSheetByName("KotLijst");
kotlijst.getRange(7, 1, kotlijst.getLastRow()-4,
  kotlijst.getLastColumn()).sort({column: 2, ascending: false});
```

Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

I did a bit of experimenting and I found the extra rows didn't get added as long as I had two or more rows after the range being sorted.